# how can I make the payment from my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, payment-gateway

I am developing an iPhone app. Using this app, we can make the online purchase.

To purchase the item, user has to make the payment. We can use web service to make payment. (eg: from iphone app, we can get user credit/debit card details. And the payment will happen in the server side. After payment, the user will get the response.) **(But I don't know whether Apple will accept this app or not).**

My question is; Is there any other way to make the payment from my iPhone app ?

I am not clear with "Apple Payment Gateway". I don't know how to use it.

If anyone having knowledge, please share with us.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you could implement the payment feature in your application by two way

1-> Apple's Apps-purchase.

Check the step by step tutorial for implementatuing In-App purchase in your application

[iPhone Tutorial – In-App Purchases](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/)

2-> By using third party payment geteway and **accepted by Appple.** (eg. Paypal).

**The reason f using 3rd party payment gateway in iPhone Application.**

> Apple reject the application
>   which use **In-App purchase**  for the
>   purchasing of physical goods.

Comment: @jfalexvijay : Accept the answer if it help you to clear you doubt .